# Нужна ли запятая перед "что"?

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, нужна ли запятая в следующем предложении?

***Тут еще неизвестно(,) что лучше: вылет на групповой стадии или разгромное поражение в "плей-офф"?***

Answer (score 3):

Тут еще неизвестно, **что** лучше: **вылет** на групповой стадии **или** разгромное **поражение** в плей-офф.

Запятая ставится. Это сложноподчиненное предложение **с придаточным изъяснительным**. ЧТО ― союзное слово, в придаточном предложении оно выполняет функцию **обобщающего слова**.